# Add WHERE to PDO query if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, jquery-autocomplete

I have a MySQL query with PDO:

```
$ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
$query = "SELECT * FROM table where name like :term";
$query .= $filterquery;
$result = $conn->prepare($query);
$result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
$result->execute();
```

I'm using the autocomplete jquery code for this "term".

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'suggest_zip.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                term: request.term,
                filter: '1'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }

})
```

If you look at the first block of code, you can see I tried $query .= $filerquery. 
$filterquery is defined here:

```
 $filter = "%".$_GET['filter']."%";

 if($filter = '1'){
        $filterquery = 'WHERE allowed = 1';
    }
 else{
        $filterquery = 'WHERE allowed = 1 OR allowed = 0';
    }
```

So what I want to do is search my database for records where allowed = 1 when the jquery variable filter = 1. Else it should search for every record (it's either 1 or 0).

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: `if($filter = '1'){` is an assignment. Were it a comparison it  still wouldn't work with `%xyz%`. You'd also end up with two `WHERE` clauses in your concatenated SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Ajax request URL to

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'suggest_zip.php?filter=' + ($('#your_checkbox_selector').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0 ),
    //...
```

Also, fix your PHP condition

```
//This is an assignment and then it's always evaluated true (since equal to 1)
if($filter = '1'){
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot! I want to thank to other people who answered as well, because a combination of all answer helped me to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

**Make your where part like this**

```
$filter_con = $_POST['filter'];

$filter = "%".$_POST['filter']."%";

`enter code here` if($filter_con == '1'){
        $filterquery = 'AND allowed = 1';
    }
 else{
        $filterquery = 'AND allowed = 1 OR allowed = 0';
    }
```

1:-You are using AJAX `type: "POST"` so use `$_POST` not `$_GET`
2:-no need to use

```
$result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
```

it'll also work:-

```
$result->bindValue("term",$ac_term);
```

IN last when you get execute the get value by

```
$result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an assignment:

```
if($filter = '1')
```

You have to use `==`

```
if($filter == '1') {
    $filterquery = 'WHERE allowed = 1';
}
else {
    $filterquery = 'WHERE allowed = 1 OR allowed = 0';
}
```

The shortest way in one line:

```
$filterquery = $filter == '1' ? 'WHERE allowed = 1' : 'WHERE allowed = 1 OR allowed = 0';
```